# Docker registry behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, docker-registry

I am trying to  install a docker registry container behind a nginx reverse proxy on a subdirectory. I already have setup a git server with redirection like so:

```
location /git/ {
rewrite ^/git/(.*) /$1 break;
rewrite ^/git$ /$1 break;
proxy_pass http://localhost:4001;
```

It resolves all requests to /git correctly.

When I try to use the same configuration for my registry, it resolves the example.com\registry\ path correct to \ of the registry, but when I call \registry\v2 I end up at example.com\v2.

```
location /registry/{
rewrite ^/registry/(.*) /$1 break;
rewrite ^/registry$ /$1 break;
proxy_pass http://192.168.0.201:3004;
```

I have already tried to switch the rewrites on and off or change the proxy_pass url to /v2  but nothing works correct.
The registry container itself works and is available at http://192.168.0.201:3004

**How can I setup the registry on my site at example.com\registry\ that ist works?(including the v2 subsite?)**

Software im using:

- debian 9.3
- nginx:1.10.3
- docker registry:latest(should be 2.6)

Comment: The API doesn't support being located anywhere but / as best I've seen. You'll need to use a dns name for the registry rather than a subdirectory.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/425